# MongoDB GeoNear Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoid, nosql-aggregation, nosql

The question is:

Consider the following location: [-72, 42] and the range (circle) of radius 2 around this point.  Write a query to find all the states that intersect this range (circle). Then, you should return the total population and the number of cities for each of these states.  Rank the states based on number of cities.

I have written this so far:

db.zips.find({loc: {$near: [-72, 42], $maxDistance: 2}})

and a sample output of that is:
{ "city" : "WOODSTOCK", "loc" : [ -72.004027, 41.960218 ], "pop" : 5698, "state" : "CT", "_id" : "06281" }

In SQL i would simply do a group by "state", how would i be able to do that here while also counting all the cities and total population?

Comment: I don't think it's sufficient to group by state to do all the things you want to do in SQL or in MongoDB.  But how is the find doing what you want?  You want all the states that intersect this range - that's not what you are finding here - you are finding all _cities_ that are within that radius.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you follow the mongoimport routine for its zipcode data (i brought mine into a collection called zips7):

mongoimport --db mydb --collection zips7 --type json --file c:\users\drew\downloads\zips.json

or

mongoimport --db mydb --collection zips7 --type json --file /data/playdata/zips.json

(depending on your OS and paths)

then

db.zips7.ensureIndex({loc:"2d"})

```
db.zips7.find({loc: {$near: [-72, 42], $maxDistance: 2}}).forEach(function(doc){
   db.zips8.insert(doc);
});
```

note that db.zips7.stats() shows like 30k rows and zips8 has 100 rows

```
 db.zips8.aggregate( { $group :
 { _id : "$state",
   totalPop : { $sum : "$pop" },
   town_count:{$sum:1} 
 }}
 )


 {
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "RI",
                        "totalPop" : 39102,
                        "town_count" : 10
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "MA",
                        "totalPop" : 469583,
                        "town_count" : 56
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "CT",
                        "totalPop" : 182617,
                        "town_count" : 34
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax in mongoid

```
Zips.where(:loc => {"$within" => {"$centerSphere"=> [[lng.to_f,lat.to_f],miles.to_f/3959]}})
```

Example:

```
Zips.where(:loc => {"$within" => {"$centerSphere"=> [[-122.4198185,37.7750454],2.0/3959]}})
```